# Laravel issue on passing image data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to upload image for an icon image on my project. When POST this function i receive and error says

> Laravel created by does not have a default value

when I already add the created_by field on my data list,  below is my code :

```
public function postAddProject($dev_id)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required|max:100',
            'address2' => 'required_with:address3|max:100',
            'address3' => 'nullable|max:100',
            'zipcode' => 'required|numeric|digits:5',
            'attachment' => 'mimes:jpeg,png'
        ]);

        $data['developer_id'] = $dev_id;
        $data['status'] = 'active';
        $data['created_by'] = auth()->user()->id;

        $project = Project::create($data);

        if (!empty($data['attachment'])) {
            $attachment_file = $data['attachment'];
            $logo_file_contents = file_get_contents($attachment_file);
            $imageData = [
                'data' => $logo_file_contents,
                'mime_type' => $attachment_file->getClientMimeType(),
                'size' => mb_strlen($logo_file_contents),
                'extension' => $attachment_file->getClientOriginalExtension()
            ];

            // $imageData = self::optimizeImage($imageData);

            $imageMedia = Media::create([
                'category' => 'project-icon',
                'mimetype' => $imageData['mime_type'],
                'data' => $imageData['data'],
                'size' => $imageData['size'],
                'created_by' => auth()->user()->id,
                'filename' => 'project_' . date('Y-m-d_H:i:s') . "." . $imageData['extension']
            ]);

            $project->logo_media()->associate($imageMedia);
            $project->save();
        }

        $dev_id = $project->developer_id;

        return redirect()->route('admin.developers.projects.index', ['dev_id' => $dev_id])->withStatus(__('Admin successfully created.'));
    }
```

Comment: And you are sure that `auth()->user()->id` returns and ID? Please provide a table-structure or migration file as well

Comment: Just change your `$data['created_by'] = auth()->user()->id;` to `$data['created_by'] = auth()->user()->id ?? 0;`. This should remove the error. However, if `0` is being saved, you should check why no User ID is available in the `Auth::user()` object.

Answer (score 1):

`Created_by` is the table field which is used to mention the data created time . You should not overwrite it .

This field will be automatically filled by `mysql` and `laravel`. 
You should add your `user_id` in any other field like `user_id` . 
Just remove the following line .

```
$data['created_by'] = auth()->user()->id;
```

And create new field in table for `user_id` and add `auth()->user()->id` in that field .

Comment: Hi thanks for your input, I add it because the error appear even without adding it

Comment: Remove that line also in imageMedia

Comment: What is your table's field type? for `created_by` ?

Comment: BigNum - Not null

Comment: change the Not null into `null` . Just give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Try to add such code at the beginning of the script.

```
$user = auth()->user();
if(is_null($user)){
    throw new \Exception('Error auth user');
}

$data['created_by'] = $user->id;
```

Comment: Hi Nick, auth user always existed because its getting the login user data, I even dd it